# I want to enable data roaming on sim module SIM 7600 E-H using AT Commands

Tags: arduino, at-command, roaming

I am working on sim module SIM700E-h and using Sakura Sim Card. I want to use this sim module for data(internet).So according to me we need to check 3 things.

1) International data roaming is enabled in the module

2) Make sure that the module is set to ONLY connect to 4G LTE networks

3) Make sure that the APN of the module is set to 'sakura'

So, i am using Arduino IDE for making serial communication with the module.

(2)I have set the module to LTE only by using the AT Command `AT+CNMP`

(3) I have set the module APN to sakura using AT Command `AT+CGDCONT`

But i am unable to enable data roaming I checked command `AT+CREG` which gives output (0,3) but I want output to be (0,5)
So you help me to enable data roaming to make `AT+CREG to (0,5)`
i have attached the sim module manual too.[enter link description here](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/6/6d/SIM7600E-H-4G-HAT-Manual-EN.pdf)

I have Arduino Nano too , so if there is any so;ution using Arduino it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, default AT commands setting DON'T block roaming registration. You have to explicitly prevent it, for example by setting manually the operator through `AT+COPS=1,0,<operator>` (you can verify it by querying `AT+COPS?`: the expected value is `+COPS: 0,...`, which means automatic choice).

So, since `+CREG: x,3` means "registration denied", it is probably due to network limitation. Cellular operators have agreement with specific foreign operators, that make their SIMs register when they are abroad:

- It might happen that the foreign operator has low coverage in some specific zones of the foerign country
- It might happen that the foreign operator has a good coverage, but not for 4G
- It might happen that the agreement between cellular operators don't involve 4G

Comment: I think that do we need to make some setting in the sim module for data roaming?

Comment: No. Just I wrote, you have to explicitely send specific command to forbid it. If you didn't send any of this commands, the only remaining option is something related to operator's restrictions (do your contract allow roaming? What happens if you place the SIM in your Mobile Phone?)

Comment: When I place in my mobile phone it works but the speed is very low for internet surfing.

Comment: This may prove that there's not 4G coverage for your operator in roaming, so forcing the module to _ make sure that the module is set to ONLY connect to 4G LTE networks_ leads to registration denial.

Comment: the operator thats Sakura internet told that it would only connect to 4G LTE configured module. I am using the waveshare company SIM7600E-H 4G HAT, so both are 4G so it should connect i think so.